# Firefox crashes Cinnamon in Virtualbox if 3d is enabled

Tags: virtualbox, firefox, cinnamon

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, fully updated in a VirtualBox environment.  VirtualBox is Version 6.1.38_Ubuntu r153438.  Ubuntu on the guest is pretty generic - I've got Docker but not much else.

My host is Ubuntu 22.04, also fully updated.  Also running Cinnamon with a "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti with Max-Q Design" card and running in NVIDIA On-Demand mode.

If I start with the VirtualBox "Enable 3D acceleration" option (regardless of the "Graphics Controler" type) Cinnamon crashes almost on startup of Firefox (version 113.0.2), sometimes with console errors (i.e., no window system, just the text console) and many times with just a blank black screen.  Everything else seems to work fine (Chrome, command line, etc.)

Firefox on the guest has been uninstalled from snap, reinstalled with snap and reinstalled with apt.  Nothing has changed.

I'm struggling a bit to locate the log files that might point me in the right direction.  This is a new thing so it's an update of the host or guest that is causing this.

I've checked `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/dmesg`, and `~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.*` on the guest.  I don't see anything interesting in any of these files on the guest or the host.  However, I may easily be looking for the wrong thing.

I'm looking for some pointers on how to fix this.  The VBox guest *is* slower without the 3D setting but it's not too bad.  Are there other log files and/or specific things I should be looking for on either side that might point me to the error?

Thanks for any pointers to help debug this.